# Check the manual that corresponds to your mysql server version for the right syntax to use near '? and password=?'

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jframe

The code snippet from my java program is given below

```
String IQuery = "select customername, address from `customeraccount` where emailaddress=? and password=?";
                    System.out.println("Connecting to a selected database...");

                    // STEP 3: Open a connection
                    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
                    System.out.println("Connected database successfully...");
                    PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(IQuery);
                    stmt.setString(1, username);
                    stmt.setString(2,pwd);
                    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
                    while(rs.next()){
                        detailName.setText(rs.getString("customername"));
                        detailAddress.setText(rs.getString("address"));
                    }
```

---

In the above snippet I am able to fetch data from customeraccount table and display it on jframe interface. But when I check the eclipse console an error with title message appears.

Comment: Try single quotes around the `?` in your SQL query. I assume these columns are strings.

Comment: @dave What?? What is that supposed to accomplish?

Comment: Your code looks good to me. When you refer to the eclipse console, are you saying you're trying to execute this query directly with the `?` placeholders? Or do you mean you get an error in the console while executing your Java program?

Comment: @lc I was guessing that the SQL syntax error suggested by the question title was caused by string values not being wrapped in quotes. If `setString()` takes care of that, then I'm barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: If you get your result then the query worked, the error comes from somewhere else.

Comment: @dave The `?` is a *placeholder*. This is a parameterized query, i.e. the Right Way(TM) to handle a database query with user input.

Comment: @lc. this error is while executing java program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I was trying to execute the query again in a later statement. Honest mistake from my side. A good nights sleep can refresh your brain you see